# BGP regular expression .+_.+_.+_.+_.+_.+_.+_.+_.+_.+_.+_.+

Tags: cisco, routing, router, bgp, acl

could anyone tell me what `ip as-path access-list 100 deny .+_.+_.+_.+_.+_.+_.+_.+_.+_.+_.+_.+` stands for?!

I searched over the internet for the meaning of this regular expression, but I was unable to find any info.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Every time you see `.+_`, that regular expression represents a single BGP autonomous system.  This as-path list denies BGP as paths equal to or longer than 12 paths long.

The regular expression works because `.` represents any character, `+` is a wild card which optionally repeats the previous character an unlimited number of times, and `_` represents the space between the autonomous system paths.  For more information, refer to the [Cisco IOS Regular Expression guide](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_2/termserv/configuration/guide/tcfaapre_ps1835_TSD_Products_Configuration_Guide_Chapter.html#wp1022889), or this [INE BGP Regular Expressions blog](http://blog.ine.com/2008/01/06/understanding-bgp-regular-expressions/).

Comment: Hello Mike,

thank you for your help and clarification. Very useful.

Best regards.

Comment: you are most welcome good luck with your project

Comment: As additional info, IOS has long supported 'bgp maxas-limit n' to make it easier to restrict AS-path size, however it is obviously global, while as-path ACL you can call more surgically.

Answer (score -1):

It'll be matching 12 AS-path list. But, I think a more appropriate way of matching it would be ^[0-9]+_[0-9]+_[0-9]+_[0-9]+_[0-9]+_[0-9]+_[0-9]+_[0-9]+_[0-9]+_[0-9]+_[0-9]+_[0-9]+$, because the expression you mentioned might just match any character ie. special characters and alphabets included.

Comment: AS-path regular expression are not 'normal' regular expressions, it's already a given that only numbers can be  used.

Comment: I'm not completely sure this would work the way the OP needs it to.  `[0-9]+[0-9]+` doesn't account for the space between autonomous system paths.  In plain terms, it says to match 0-9 (`[0-9]`) an infinite amount of times (`+`) followed directly by another set of infinite 0-9 sets (`[0-9]+`).